# Python: How to extend or append multiple elements in list comprehension format?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'd like to get a nice neat list comprehension for this code or something similar!

```
extra_indices = []
for i in range(len(indices)):
    index = indices[i]
    extra_indices.extend([index, index + 1, index +2])
```

Thanks!

Edit* The indices are a list of integers.  A list of indexes of another array.

For example if indices is [1, 52, 150] then the goal (here, this is the second time I've wanted two separate actions on continuously indexed outputs in a list comprehension)

Then extra_indices would be [1, 2, 3, 52, 53, 54, 150, 151, 152]

Comment: what is len/value of indices here?

Comment: For starters you could iterate on the list like: `for index in indices:`. But show us an example: for an `indices` value how should `extra_indices` look like?

Comment: what does the list `indices` contain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two loops in list comp -

```
extra_indices = [index+i for index in indices for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: what is value/type of indices but? Explain a bit clearer

Comment: Sorry, you mean to ask what is the type of `indices`? From OPs code it looks like it is a list/tuple of integers/float

Comment: Yes.. It seems in first look but what if it contains string or any other type. Sorry The OP must mention this Question clearly.

Comment: @BHappyBHarsham, I think OP wants to say that his code works but he wants list comprehension. But you are right, OP can clarify that

Comment: Yes We could answer this with different methods. Anyway +1..Keep Going!

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to see, thanks!  Yeah you read my mind correctly, indices is a list of ints :)

Comment: @Fosa, if the answers works for you, can you accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 4):

code below should do the equivalant of your code, assuming indices is a list of integer

```
from itertools import chain
extra_indices = list(chain(*([x,x+1,x+2] for x in indices)))

>>> indices = range(3)
>>> list(chain(*([x,x+1,x+2] for x in indices)))
>>> [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you very much this is perfect!